# function that stop the script in python like stop() in R

Tags: python, terminate

I am writing a script in python and I would like to stop the scipt in the middle to see the objects and things. I used `sys.exit()` in `pyscripter` and everything is fine, but when I switch to `spyder`, the python interpreter is killed and I cannot read anything after the script is stopped.

How to fix it?